# flask-wtforms field required

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

how i can add tag required on this flask code :

```
{{ form.youtube_href(type='url', class='form-control') }}
```

actual output is :

```
<input class="form-control" id="youtube_href" name="youtube_href" value="" type="url">
```

need this output bat give error :

```
<input class="form-control" id="youtube_href" name="youtube_href" value="" type="url" required>
```

im tried this bat give error :

```
{{ form.youtube_href(type='url', class='form-control', 'required') }}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of WTForms 2.2 (June 2nd, 2018), fields now render the `required` attribute if they have a validator that sets the `required` flag, such as `DataRequired` and `InputRequired`. If for some reason you don't want to render the attribute, you can pass `required=False`. Or if you want to disable all browser validation, you can set the `novalidate` attribute in the `form` tag. In general you should prefer to leave browser validation enabled, because it prevents a request/response for simple validation, which is desirable.

---

You are passing a positional argument after keyword arguments, which is a syntax error.  Instead, pass `required=True`, which will set a bare attribute on the tag.  Check the flags on a field to see if a `Required` validator was set: `field.flags.required` is a boolean.  Create a `URLField` rather than passing the type manually.

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms.fields.html5 import URLField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired

class MyForm(Form):
    youtube_href = URLField(validators=[InputRequired()])

form = MyForm()
print(form.youtube_href(required=form.youtube_href.flags.required))
# <input id="youtube_href" name="youtube_href" required type="url" value="">
```

Answer (score 3):

To those who simply want to add the `required` attribute to their html input, this can be accomplished by following the comment mentioned by Raja Simon above. Simply call your field name in your *template* with `required='required'` Example:

```
<form>
  ...
  {{myform.my_name_field(required='required')}}
  {{myform.my_email_field(required='required')}}
  ...
</form>
```

The Above code will result in fields like so:

```
<input id="my_name_field" name="my_name_field" required="required" type="text" value="">
```