# WTForms Flask(wtf_flask) validators how to include "required" attribute for RadioField

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

What I am basically looking for is the RadioField equivalent validator for `InputRequired()` for WTForms. What I am mean is when you try to submit a form without entering any text into a StringField field that has the `InputRequired()` validator, The user gets a prompt above the text field saying `"Please fill out this field"`. I want the User to have to pick either `male` or `female`.

This is easily done in HTML forms by just including the `required` attribute in your HTML form. But I cannot seem to understand what the equivalent is in WTForms for RadioField. `InputRequired()` and `DataRequired()` are both just for Input text fields and don't seem to work with any other type of fields.

If I have the below very simple WTForms class for signup form, `InputRequired()` works great in this instance as it gives the user the prompt `"Please fill out this field"` If they forget to either put in their `name` or `surname`. The form will not submit unless they give input into these fields.

```
class Signup(FlaskForm):
name = StringField('First Name', validators=[InputRequired()])
surname = StringField('Last Name', validators=[InputRequired()])
submit = SubmitField('Signup')
```

But if I have the below form that has a RadioField, What is the equivalent validator to force the User to pick `Male` or `Female` and if they do not pick one I want to give the prompt `"please fill out this field"`? (I am using BootStrap) I cannot seem to find any information about it. Does it exist? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307888/flask-wtforms-field-required) question here in the second answer basically had what I am looking for `Required="Required"` but that has since been made obsolete since June 2018. I have tried pretty much every approach with trying to use `InputRequired()` or `DataRequired()` with `RadioField` but no success.

```
class StudentPersonalQs(FlaskForm):
gender = RadioField('Gender', choices = [('Male','Male'),('Female','Female')])
age = SelectField('Age', choices = [('12', '12'), ('13', '14'),('15', '15'), ('16', '16'),('17', '17'), ('18+', '18+')])
submit = SubmitField('Signup')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, you can only use this way to achieve this currently:

```
{% for subfield in form.age %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ subfield(required="required") }}</td>
        <td>{{ subfield.label }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```